# RTSP Streaming in Objective C

Tags: ios, video-streaming, rtsp

I need RSTP Live Streaming. I started R&D, but I can't figure it out. Someone suggested using FFMPEG library, but I don't know how to add FFMPEG library to my project. How do I get Live RTSP Streaming?

Please give me idea and any RTSP Live Streaming Video Sample code.

Comment: Have you got the solution for this >

Comment: you can use : https://github.com/maknapp/vlckitSwiftSample : this one in swift... it is used for play RTSP stream

Answer (score 5):

RTSP is quite simple protocol by itself, just reading [RFC2326](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt) will help a lot. Source code examples you can find, for example, at [former live.com](http://live555.com) or [jrtplib](http://research.edm.uhasselt.be/~jori/page/index.php?n=CS.Jrtplib) (it's RTP/RTCP library, but as I said RTSP is very simple) 
You'll need ffmpeg (or other encoder/decoder library) later. There are a lot of ffmpeg tutorials, for example, [this one quite old, but quite good](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html), there are plenty of source code on github, for example, [here](https://github.com/lajos/iFrameExtractor)